# Applying wrapper class directly on elements instead of surrounding div?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

First, this is my **HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navi">
      <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
      <ul><!--
        --><li><a href="#" class="navlink">Link 1</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#" class="navlink">Link 2</a></li><!--
      --></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 50em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header,
.navi {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background: grey;
}

.navi {
    background: green;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.navi ul {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
}

.navi li {
    background: orange;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navilink {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

.logo {
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    background: fuchsia;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnwCq/)
[Fullscreen Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnwCq/embedded/result/)

You see, the wrapper ensures that there is always some kind of gap between content and edge of the viewport and beyond a certain point (50 em), the `.wrapper` doesn't exceeds any further.

The code I posted here works, but I would like to know if there is any chance to get rid of `<div class="wrapper">` achieving the same result. I already tried to apply the `.wrapper` class directly to the elements, but that isn't working - why?

*To clarify:* My aim is it to make the markup cleaner. That's why I am interested in a solution then ensures that the elements behave like in the example I posted, but without the use of `<div class="wrapper">`. The class `.wrapper` has to stay of course, it's just that `div` that strikes me. Thats why I tried to add `.wrapper` directly to the elements.

Comment: I would really like to help but the answer is not very clear to me. Do you want to take out the wrapper class where the header is or where the class content is, or both? Perhaps you can describe the final look you are trying to achieve would make my understanding of the problem better.

Comment: @AngeloMiranda Please see my edit, I hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the wrapper div, and add the two CSS properties to the content div..

```
.content { 
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 50em;
}
```